# copying files on different machines doesn't work in C

Tags: c, file, sockets

I'm on Windows I asked a similar question earlier(I solved that problem). I made a server/client program that copies a file from client to server. It works good when server and client are on the same machine but the moment I move the client to a different machine, it fails. I don't get any errors but if I click on the copied file after copying(writing to the new file on server) it doesn't show anything or it shows gibberish. It works fine when server/client are on the same machine. `BUFSIZE` equals 512 bytes.

Server:

```
FILE* copyFile;
fopen_s(&copyFile, ch, "wb"); // ch equals the full path to the file
if (copyFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}

char buf[BUFSIZE];
size_t size = BUFSIZE;

while (size == BUFSIZE)
{
    int res = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("3 error %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
        break;
    }
    size = fwrite(buf, 1, res, copyFile);
}
fclose(copyFile);
```

Client:

```
FILE* originalFile;
fopen_s(&originalFile, c, "rb"); // c equals the full path to the file
if (originalFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}

char buf[BUFSIZE];
size_t size = BUFSIZE;
                
while (size == BUFSIZE)
{
    size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, originalFile);
    int r = send(ClientSocket, buf, size, 0);
    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("1 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
        break;
    }
}
fclose(originalFile);
```

What is the problem here? Why does it work on the same machine and not on different machines

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use TCP as protocol, you have to remember that it's a *streaming* protocol, without messages or any boundaries. It's just a stream of bytes. And as such, a single call to `recv` may not match a single call to `send`, it could actually "receive" *less* that requested. And if that happens, you will break the receiving loop, even though there might be more data to receive.

You need to indicate the end of the file some way. Either by first sending a (fixed size!) message header for the file-size, or send a special byte or byte-sequence indicating the end of the file (which is rather hard with arbitrary binary files).